# PostgreSQL returns wrong date_part for week for date 2021-01-01

Tags: postgresql, week-number

If I run the following query I get really strange results. I get **week 1** (as expected) only starting from Monday 4th of January. I using this in a group by query to count covid cases per week and this totaly ruins my day :/

```
SELECT date_part('week', '2021-01-01'::date) as week, date_part('year', '2021-01-01'::date) as year;
week year
53   2021
```

Version: *PostgreSQL 12.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.3.0) 9.3.0, 64-bit*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) 'week' uses the [ISO definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) for the first week.

To get the corresponding (ISO) year, use `'isoyear'`

```
SELECT date_part('week', '2021-01-01'::date) as week, 
       date_part('isoyear', '2021-01-01'::date) as year;
```

The above correctly [returns](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=316b0cb201a1493a67e0708b96e84896) 53, 2020

Comment: Thank you. It never occured to me (and it still doesnt make sense to me) that the week number „reach into” the new year.